VBA retrieve object data
I have an object (JS) i my VBA which is returned from using jsonParser function. The data returned is in the image below

My code includes the following to retrieve the registration and make etc.
            assign parseToVb(Response, js, , ok), result
            'Fill in Results
            'Make
                Cells(RR, "L").Value = js.make
            'Model
                Cells(RR, "M").Value = js.model
            'Colour
                Cells(RR, "N").Value = js.primaryColour

And this works as I would expect. But what I cant do is reciver the "expiryDate" that is within the motTests
I have tried
MOT = js.motTests.motTestNumber.completedDate etc
and
MOT = js.motTests[motTestNumber} ..
but this isnt returning anything. Ideally I want to access this data (expiryDate) without entering the test number as I wont always know it.
Any help or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Try js.motTests[0].expiryDate

Sorry try js.motTests[1].expiryDate, collections are 1-based. You should be able to loop through them with Dim mot; For each mot in j.motTests; debug.print mot.expiryDate; Next

Can you provide a reference or more detail for the parseToVb step?
